# Scheduling Software

Tags: scheduling, meetings

We have a couple self service platforms which sometimes some users need additional assistance with and someone to walk them through the process.

I am looking for an application we can embed into the Help Page on these Self Service Platforms where the following can occur:

1. Suggest options: The User who needs assistance and choose times that work for them from a list of available times we pre-define
2. Time Confirmed: Have the list of options go to the support team and the support team confirms the proffered option and inserts the skype meeting details (or preferably auto generated)
3. Booked in both calendars The meeting is booked and added automatically to both of calendars with the skype meeting details

With the additional functionality to request to reschedule or cancel. Would like to also see the ability to schedule workshops/seminars/classes where users can register and join in mass and provide those as options

I have found multiple applications that would get us half way there, but nothing that allows the skype meeting details to be inputted.

Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.